# Select in IF statement, MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to do something like this in My MySQL stored proc:

```
if val > SELECT numericalValue FROM table where userId=theUserId then ..
```

Is it ok to do that, or do I have to store `numericalValue` in a temporary?

Comment: when you say "store numericValue in a temporary," do you mean in a temporary table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a select statement within an if statement.

It needs to be in parentheses and it must evaluate to a single row each time, so it works well for sums and counts, and if you are returning a field's value, you will want to use LIMIT 1

You could also use a variable, that would also work.

Comment: Oh, it was the missing brackets, `if val > (SELECT numericalValue FROM table where userId=theUserId) then ..`

Comment: Yes, the brackets would be why that did not run.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to, but it would make things more convenient if you plan to reuse the selection elsewhere in your code.

Also, you should use the following syntax as a guideline:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_condition(IN var1 INT) 
BEGIN 
 IF (val > SELECT numericalValue FROM table where userId='theUserId')  
  THEN SELECT 'greater'; 
  ELSE SELECT 'less than or equal'; 
 END IF; 
END|
```